# How to remove the first special character in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sample Data

```
+----+-----------+
| Id | Name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | $John     |
|  2 | $Carol    |
|  3 | $Mike     | 
|  4 | $Sam      |
|  5 | $David$Mohan$ |
|  6 | Robert$Ram$   |  
|  8 | Maxwell$ |
+----+-----------+
```

I need to remove the only $ first character

Need output  :

```
+----+-----------+
| Id | Name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | John     |
|  2 | Carol    |
|  3 | Mike     | 
|  4 | Sam      |
|  5 | David$Mohan$ |
|  6 | Robert$Ram$   |  
|  8 | Maxwell$ |
+----+-----------+

Select REPLACE(col,'$','') from Tbl
```

I have tried with Replace and Substring but still missing the point . 
Can anyone suggest me .

Comment: Can you show exactly what you have tried?

Comment: Have you [read this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213141/how-to-remove-specific-characters-from-strings-in-sql)?

Comment: @Martin check i have added what  i have tried

Comment: Question is already answered, as @Martin identified: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213142

Comment: @mohan111 You mean any special character or $ specifically?

Comment: only $ @MenelaosBakopoulos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression and string operations:

```
(case when col like '$%' then substr(col, 2) else col end)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 1) = '$' THEN SUBSTRING(Name, 2, LENGTH(Name)-1)   
    ELSE Name
END
FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with just on invokation of `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(name, '^$', '') name from mytable
```

Regexp `'^$'` means: a dollar sign at the beginning of the string. If the string does not match the regexp, `regexp_replace()` returns it untouched.

Comment: when I'm wrapping this procedure it is not working and as select it is working

Comment: @mohan111: to start with: are you running MySQL 8.0, or an earlier version?

Comment: 8.0.13-commercial

Comment: @mohan111: ok so this should work for you. I cannot tell what the probelm is with your procedure, but probably this is not related to `regexp_replace()` itself...

Comment: If i take the statement from procedure and pass the inputs in WHERE condition it is working fine but while calling from procedure it is giving NULLS

Comment: Not working in my procedure but still nice solution @GMB